# How is page data rearranged after clustered index is created?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, database-internals, data-pages

Can anyone please explain what happens at the page level when clustered indexes are created? How do pages rearrange data once clustered indexes are created?

Comment: I asked a similar question, and I can't find it. IIRC the logical page manager links virtual pages to physical block pages, so they're not actually arranged in a clustered fashion on the physical medium. I found it to be kind of confusing too. Moreover, the records within the pages aren't actually ordered anyway (you have to look up the slot array) Anyway good luck on this one.